# live change any site visualization properties

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Is there a way to load a site (or point to a web page) through a custom page able to grab the original site's element and change their visualization properties?

For example: if there is an on-line site with red-borded paragraphs, it is possible create a page able to point at this site and turning its paragraph visualization border to blue?

**UPDATE:** 
Very very important, I absolutely need to be able to ***navigate*** the target site. 
 I'm looking for a way to create a "visualization layer" which has to be transparent for the final user.

**UPDATE 2:** 
I have tried creating a php page and using cURL with this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.google.com');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

 $output = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

print( $output );
```

The page is loaded but missed some elements and the images. I is also not possible to navigate / search through it.

**UPDATE 3:** 
I have found an extention for both FireFox and Chrome which is really close to my aim: `"Stylish"`
This add on allows to live change any site css proprerty and save it in order to reload them every time you'll visit the page.

Now my question is: How can I do the same creating a dedicated page to load and change visualization of a specific site?

---

**FINAL EDIT:**

In order to continue this question with a more relevant arguments I decided to ask a new one: 
 [create a php proxy page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010316/create-a-php-proxy-page)

Answer (score 2):

Use php CURL functions to grab website and then replace css of page with your own, or just embed css rules into file with help of phpQuery library.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest to create a php page to grab the "original page code" into my "visualization page". Will I be able to navigate through the original site from my page or it will be only a static copy with a different color style?

Comment: Yes, link will persist working. But only if they begins with http;//sitename. Otherwise you should replace **href="/** with **href="http;//sitename/**. I did same with fake page of interpol wanted persons with photos of my friends )

Comment: But I don't know the target site code or its links destinations, I only have the main url. I need to create a "window" and see the site through. I've already tested with an iframe, but unfortunately it allows navigation but can't reach the element cross-domain.

Comment: Not navigate within your website, links will open original site. But you can replace links to original site with yoursite.com/replacer.php?page=ORIGINAL_SITE_URL and retrieve content in th same way like first page

Comment: You can grab target site code and work with its DOM like with jQuery working with your own site.